# Multiple comma separated string columns to multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a scenario where I have data like below in #Testdata temp table.

```
create table #Testdata(SomeID int, OtherID int, Data varchar(max), Data2 VARCHAR(MAX))
insert #Testdata select 1, 9, '18,20,22', '12,13'
insert #Testdata select 2, 8, '17,19', ''
insert #Testdata select 3, 7, '13,19,20', '14,,50'
insert #Testdata select 4, 6, '', ''
```

Now I require to show result as below.

```
|SomeId|OtherID|Data|Data2|
|1     |9      |18  |12   |
|1     |9      |20  |13   |
|1     |9      |22  |     |
|2     |8      |17  |     |
|2     |8      |19  |     |
|3     |7      |13  |14   |
|3     |7      |19  |     |
|3     |7      |10  |50   |
|4     |6      |    |     |
```

Any responses will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Jeff Moden's string split function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) you can do the following to get the output you need, though I am sure there is a more efficient way...

```
declare @Testdata table(SomeID int, OtherID int, Data varchar(max), Data2 VARCHAR(MAX));
insert @Testdata select 1, 9, '18,20,22', '12,13';
insert @Testdata select 2, 8, '17,19', '';
insert @Testdata select 3, 7, '13,19,20', '14,,50';
insert @Testdata select 4, 6, '', '1,2,3,4,5';

with t1 as
(
    select t.SomeID
            ,t.OtherID
            ,t1.ItemNumber
            ,t1.Item as Data1
    from @Testdata t
        outer apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.Data,',') t1
), t2 as
(
    select t.SomeID
            ,t.OtherID
            ,t2.ItemNumber
            ,t2.Item as Data2
    from @Testdata t
        outer apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.Data2,',') t2
)
select isnull(t1.SomeID,t2.SomeID) as SomeID
    ,isnull(t1.OtherID,t2.OtherID) as OtherID
    ,t1.Data1
    ,t2.Data2
from t1
full join t2
    on t1.SomeID = t2.SomeID
        and t1.ItemNumber = t2.ItemNumber;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could for example install the [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden. The result set will contain both the item and item number, so with the item number you can join the 2 strings you split together.